# Crystal Report Get Group Count

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report that needs to display the group count in the group header. To be clear when I say count I don't mean the count of the details but the count of the actual group.

For example, if the report groups on field A and the report ends up creating three groups lets say X, Y, and Z. I need group X to display 1, group Y to display 2, and group Z to display 3.

I have tried adding a summary with count of field that is being grouped on but this displays the count of the rows from the detail of the group instead of the count of the group itself.

Hope this is clear. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Running total would work

Comment: Running total returns 1 for each header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula and drop it in the header.

```
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar g := 0;
g := g + 1;
```

Comment: This isn't a valid formula

Comment: So i put this in group header and it returns a 1 for each group

Comment: So I got this working by initializing g in report header to 0. Then in group header: whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar g:=g + 1; Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @shawnt00

Comment: It's been forever since I actually had to write a CR formula. I couldn't remember if that was the correct syntax and had no way to actually test it. Glad you figured out how to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

If the report is grouped by just one column, then you can put following line in a formula.

```
GroupNumber;
```

Or just drag and drop the field "Group Number" from "Special Fields".

Note: `GroupNumber` is incremented for each group. Means, if the report is grouped by more than one column, then this won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use summery field and generate it in the group footer 
[image: Group Rows Count]